# Probability : choosing bags

Tags: probability

This is one question which nobody answered it.

There are nine wrapping bags, three of which contain 2GB pen drives and the rest 1GB pen drives. There are three girls and five boys randomly select a bag each. Find the probability that

a) the girls select more bags which contain 2 GB pen drives than the boys.

b) none of the girls has a bag which contain 2 GB pen drives.

I've no idea for the question a. But for b)

My attempt is $\frac{6}{9}\cdot \frac{3}{8}+\frac{5}{8}\cdot \frac{2}{7}+\frac{4}{7}\cdot \frac{1}{6}=\frac{11}{21}$

Am I correct? And how to solve the question a) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $G$ be a random variable for the number of girls with a bag with 2Gb pens and $B$ the same for boys.

$\begin{align}
P(G>B)&=^1P(G=3)+P(G=2)+P(G=1\cap B=0)\\&=P(G=3)+P(G=2)+P(G=1)P(B=0\mid G=1)\\
P(G=3)&=\frac{3}{9}\frac{2}{8}\frac{1}{7}=\frac{1}{84}\\
P(G=2)&=\frac{3}{9}\frac{2}{8}\frac{6}{7}+\frac{3}{9}\frac{6}{8}\frac{2}{7}+\frac{6}{9}\frac{3}{8}\frac{2}{7}=\frac{3}{14}\\
P(G=0)&=^b\frac{6}{9}\frac{5}{8}\frac{4}{7}=\frac{5}{21}\\
P(G=1)&=1-(P(G=3)+P(G=2)+P(G=0))\\
&=1-(\frac{1}{84}+\frac{3}{14}+\frac{5}{21})=\frac{15}{28}\\
P(B=0\mid G=1)&=^20\\
P(G>B)&=\frac{1}{84}+\frac{3}{14}=\frac{19}{84}
\end{align}$

So **a)** $\frac{19}{84}$ and **b)** $\frac{5}{21}$

$=^1$ Note that if girls has 2 or 3 bags with 2Gb pens, they'll have more than the boys, since there will be only 1 or 0 bags left. On the other hand, if they have 1 bag with 2Gb pens, we need to count only the probability when boys have 0 bags. If girls have no bag with 2Gb, they will surely have equal or less than boys.

$=^2$ We basically have that grils having 1 bag with 2Gb means that there's only six bags left (rather than 9) with **2** bags with 2Gb, and boys will take 5 of these 6. Therefore they'll have to pick at least one bag with 2Gb pens.

$=^b$ Count the probability of not taking a bag with 2Gb in the first pick **and** neither with the second pick **and** neither with the third.